# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '0

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $catsub1 (
    pro_id INT(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    pro_name TEXT, 
    pro_de TEXT, 
    image_name VARCHAR(15), 
    ori_pri INT(10), 
    off_pri INT(10), 
    off_per INT(10), 
    sl TEXT, 
    sxl TEXT, 
    sxxl TEXT
)";
```

Error is:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '0 (pro_id INT(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, pro_name TEXT, pro_de TEXT, image_name V' at line 1

thanks in advance

Comment: Apparently `$catsub1` is 0, please check your code

Comment: The 20 in INT(20) is completely meaningless, and the 10 is almost completely meaningless

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to write `CREATE TABLE catsub1...`, without the `$`?

Is the table name `catsub1`, or are you trying to insert the value of the `$catsub1` variable as the table name? In this case, you need to set the value of `$catsub1` properly because apparently it is now `0`.

```
$catsub1 = "your_table_name";
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $catsub1 ...";
```